# How to make my expo app appear in the share list of another app?

Tags: react-native, expo

This question has been asked many times on stack overflow, but never for apps generated using the expo framework, which makes my app specific and incompatible with replies from other posts.

How can I make my expo app appear in the share list of another app? It seems the docs don't address this topic.

[image: Share menu]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

At least not in the expo managed workflow at the time I'm writing this. If that's crucial for your app, you can eject, move to the [bare workflow](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#bare-workflow) and give [react-native-share-extension](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension) a shot.

PS: There's a [feature request](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/share-extension-ios-share-intent-android). I hope they'll implement it in the (near) future.

Comment: Did you find solution for Expo?

Comment: So sad it's still not supported

Answer (score 0):

Using the configuration in app.json and specifically the android.intentFilters key,

```
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "SEND",
          "data": [
            {
              "mimeType": "text/plain"
            }
          ],
          "category": ["DEFAULT"]
        }
      ]
```

(more here https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v48.0.0/config/app/#intentfilters)

I have managed to make my app appear in the share list. However, I don't know and can't find how to get the data sent from the other app.

Any help about how to handle the received data in react?

Comment: I found it, using Philip's answer here https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/share-extension-ios-share-intent-android !